# Send JSON data from Sencha Touch to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, sencha-touch

I'm trying to send data to the server. But my code does not work. Can someone point out a mistake?

Sencha code:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: '/Blog/SavePost',
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
                        },
                        params: {
                            id: currentPost.data.Id,
                            title: currentPost.data.Title,
                            text: currentPost.data.Text,
                            authorName: currentPost.data.AuthorName,
                            authorEmail: currentPost.data.AuthorEmail,
                            postDate: currentPost.data.PostDate
                        },
                        failure: function (response) { },
                        success: function (response, opts) { }
                    });
```

MVC code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SavePost(int id, string title, string text, string authorName, string authorEmail, DateTime postDate)
    {
        Post post = new Post { Id = id, Title = title, Text = text, AuthorEmail = authorEmail, AuthorName = authorName, PostDate = postDate };
        var postRepository = new PostRepository();
        postRepository.Add(post);
        return Json();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what doesn't work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the `application/json` request header because you are not sending a JSON encoded request:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/Blog/SavePost',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        id: currentPost.data.Id,
        title: currentPost.data.Title,
        text: currentPost.data.Text,
        authorName: currentPost.data.AuthorName,
        authorEmail: currentPost.data.AuthorEmail,
        postDate: currentPost.data.PostDate
    },
    failure: function (response) { },
    success: function (response, opts) { }
});
```

Personally I would recommend having your controller action directly take the `Post` model instead of having each property as argument and then manually recopying them into a Post object:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SavePost(Post post)
{
    var postRepository = new PostRepository();
    postRepository.Add(post);
    return Json(...);
}
```

The default model binder will take care of everything. Now if you wanted to use JSON as request you could use the `JSON.stringify` method which is natively built into modern web browsers:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/Blog/SavePost',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    },        
    params: {
        post: JSON.stringify({
            id: currentPost.data.Id,
            title: currentPost.data.Title,
            text: currentPost.data.Text,
            authorName: currentPost.data.AuthorName,
            authorEmail: currentPost.data.AuthorEmail,
            postDate: currentPost.data.PostDate
        })
    },
    failure: function (response) { },
    success: function (response, opts) { }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. -- But if I use 'post: JSON.stringify' in params section, then 'post' will be null. As a result: for send data
params: {
        id: currentPost.data.Id,
        title: currentPost.data.Title,
        text: currentPost.data.Text,
        authorName: currentPost.data.AuthorName,
        authorEmail: currentPost.data.AuthorEmail,
        postDate: currentPost.data.PostDate
    },
for receive data
public ActionResult SavePost(Post post)
{
    ...
}

Comment: Hey pls see this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563417/how-to-consume-soap-web-service-in-sencha-touch.
and try to answer it...

Answer (score 2):

I have recently had similar problems with extJS and MVC but I use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to determine what requests are actually being sent and what response if any is being returned.

This tool is invaluable and I would highly recommend it!

Comment: Hey pls see this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563417/how-to-consume-soap-web-service-in-sencha-touch.
and try to answer it...